# Refreshing a Script at a URL Automatically Every Hour

Tags: php, refresh, page-refresh

We've got a script but it keeps timing out, we've upped the limits in php.ini but the script still seems to time out at some point overnight.

What I'd like to do is keep the URL to the script open in a browser window and have it automatically refresh each hour to ensure the script is running all the time.

Is there something I can insert at /index.php to do this? Perhaps a meta refresh?

Or any other ideas would be welcome, many thanks.

Comment: Seems like the best idea would be to use a cron job http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: All our scripts are running locally in our office - would it still be possible to run cron jobs? Thanks

Comment: Yeah it is possible and probably the most reliable solution. What OS are you running? If it's Windows you should check out this: http://drupal.org/node/31506 If not I can provide the answer later.

Comment: I've just added a scheduled task to run the URL in browser every hour... I'm not to sure how to test though as when I ran the task, it didn't launch the browser (but adding the job path from the run command ran what I wanted perfectly though) - will certainly hope for the best on this one, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client side refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; url=http://localhost/">
```

Server side refresh:

```
<?php header("refresh: 15; url=http://localhost/"); ?>
```

15 means refresh after 15seconds. You have to insert the url to your script instead of http://localhost/

Comment: Hey mat, thanks for your reply. The /index.php has no <head> so can the meta refresh be added to this file (or does it need to call in a header file)? And where does the server side refresh need to be inserted? (Thanks for you help, none of my developers are in the office today) :/

Comment: If you are running php on your server, you can add this line to your code: `<?php header("refresh: 15; url=http://localhost/"); ?>` but it has to be set, before any output happens. If you could add the first lines of index.php I probably could help you better.

Comment: Hey mat, sorry for the delay, the start of the file just starts with user agent and db connections (it's all running on local server though). If that helps?

Comment: The reason why I am asking is, I want to know if this index.php is only used for that single script or are u displaying different pages, where index.php is entrypoint and then continues with controllers to find the actual script and so on. If this is the only script, running over the index.php you can simply add `header("refresh: 15; url=http://localhost/");` to your php code somewhere before any html code has been outputted or any echo "" or print "" was called. After 15secs you should be redirected to localhost then.

Comment: zigo/zigobot1/index.php I want to keep refreshing zigo/zigobot1 - Code at top of index.php is <?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'Zigo (ZigoOS; ZigoOS 0.1; en-GB;) ZigoBot1/1.0.0.1');
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'zigo_brain';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
 if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

Comment: Did you try to add this line `header("refresh: 2; url=http://localhost/zigo/zigobot1/index.php");` after the code you've posted?

Comment: I added it before like this >> <?php header("refresh: 15; url=http://localhost/"); ?>
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'Zigo (ZigoOS; ZigoOS 0.1; en-GB;) ZigoBot1/1.0.0.1');

Comment: what happens? You can also use url=http://stackoverflow.com if you want to check if it's working. Do you get an error message like "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." ?

Comment: I just tested with http://www.stackoverflow.com as the URL and I ran zigo/zigobot1 in my browser and left it for a good minute or two but the page didn't refresh to stackoverflow.

Comment: I presume 15 indicates 15 seconds

Comment: yes, 15 indicates 15 secs. mh. No Error-Messages received? Until your developers are back in office, maybe you wanna try another quick and dirty-solution and just write `print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; url=http://localhost/">';` somewhere to your PHP code. For testing purposes it could work, also if it's not defined in <head>.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to be refreshing in browser still :(

Comment: Mhh, I don't understand that `header("refresh: 2; url=http://stackoverflow.com");` doesn't work and no error is given. Do you know jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Hi mat, no not familiar with jsfiddle.net - Just went on there for the first time though. This is probably quite simple and I'm not telling you the right information or something, heh. Just to clarify, should this be working: <?php
header("refresh: 2; url=http://stackoverflow.com");
ini_set('user_agent', 'Zigo (ZigoOS; ZigoOS 0.1; en-GB;) ZigoBot1/1.0.0.1'); (those are the first three lines in index.php - and I presume this should, after 2 seconds of calling the URL in browser (Firefox), refresh to stackoverflow.com?  Thanks

Comment: Usually this should work, if header is accepted. If not, there should be an error as I wrote in one of my previous comments. Add http:// in front of the url and try again please.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a timeout on the script itself could be a problem because you might not want to reset it unless really necessary (eg when it times out).

Something I used a long a time ago was the following concept.

I had two scripts, one monitoring the other.

The functional script would write a file with a timestamp after each completed loop (I'm assuming you're running some kind of loop).

Now the monitor script would be very simple, it would check the timestamp file every 30 seconds, and as soon as it noticed the timestamp was too old (eg not recently updated), it echoed a JS line that would reopen the functional script in a new window. This way the functional script will only be opened again once it stopped working.

The monitoring script would echo a line of JS to keep refreshing itself every 30 seconds (using settimeout). This approach would simulate you being behind the computer and waiting for the script to timeout and restart it.

Let me know if you need examples with this, but this is how you can solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply saratis - I don't think I would be able to implement your suggestion on my own, I would have to wait for my developers to get back into the office - thanks very much anyway though :)